# Бот не выдает ожидаемый результат

Tags: python, бот

```
bonuses={'950895778':{'1234':'12000'}, '912045858':{'1255':13000}, '911458384':{'7896':14000}, '999987311':{'1111':15000},
   '975950701':{'2222':15000}}    
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
        await message.answer("Введите номер телефона'")
        
    @dp.message_handler()
    async def echo_send(message:types.Message):
        if message.text in bonuses.keys():
            text=bonuses[message.text]
            await message.answer("Введите номер карты")
        else:
            await message.answer("Нет такой карты")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ожидаемый результат на картинке

Comment: ну а выводит что? а сам что вводишь? что в ``bonuses``?

Comment: bonuses={'950895778':['1234','12000'], '912045858':{'1255':13000}, '911458384':{'7896':14000}, '999987311':{'1111':15000},
   '975950701':{'2222':15000}}

Comment: не выдает количество очков.

Comment: а в коде ничего нет, что должно выдавать количество очков

Comment: подскажите пож, что и куда добавить. спасибо

Comment: ну уж нет уж. Такие элементарные вещи нужно уметь делать самостоятельно. Тут даже по аналогии с номером карты можно сделать! К тому же в предыдущем вопросе вам уже сказали, что и куда нужно добавить!!!

Comment: мучаюсь уже 2 день, может поможете. плиз

Comment: @Эникейщик Ну это ему не поможет.